# How to know the full URL in django before the view?

Tags: python, django

My goal is to check if the domain name redirection is really working well.

How to easily know the full URL in django before the view and even before routing if it is possible.

Cheers

Comment: A custom middleware?

Comment: sorry, i do not understand

Comment: I'm not fully sure of what you need to achieve, but if you want access to the request object, before it hits a view function, you could do so in a custom Django middleware: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/